# Memory allocation in redis

Tags: redis

After browsing some of the code of Redis, I notice that the "robj" creation is done by calling "createObject" function, which in turn calls "malloc" to alloc memory. So whenever a request comes(e.g. SET uid 1234), there will be a memory allocation process.

My question is, why not pre-allocate the space to reduce memory allocation cost? because of different object size?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> > My question is, why not pre-allocate the space to reduce memory allocation cost? because of different object size?

What you describe is the job of a memory allocator. Building that kind of logic within Redis isn't trivial.

By default, Redis uses [jemalloc](http://www.canonware.com/jemalloc/) memory allocator on Linux.

Jemalloc has several optimizations to reduce memory allocation overheads. Read the following links to learn how jemalloc helps -

1. [Facebook Engineering blog on Jemalloc](http://www.facebook.com/notes/facebook-engineering/scalable-memory-allocation-using-jemalloc/480222803919)
2. [Jemalloc Paper from 2006](http://people.freebsd.org/~jasone/jemalloc/bsdcan2006/jemalloc.pdf)

When Redis introduced Jemalloc, lots of memory management problems just disappeared. Here is what [antirez (author of redis) had to say](http://antirez.com/post/everything-about-redis-24.html) about introducing jemalloc:

> [snip] An allocator is a serious thing. Since we introduced the specially
>   encoded data types Redis started suffering from fragmentation. We
>   tried different things to fix the problem, but basically the Linux
>   default allocator in glibc sucks really, really hard.
>
> Including jemalloc inside of Redis was a huge win. Every single case of fragmentation in real world
>   systems was fixed by this change, and also the amount of memory used
>   dropped a bit.

P.S. You are likely going to get better and more informed answers on the redis-db mailing list

Comment: You brings me all info about this subject, Thanks!